# JPA: How to associate entities with relationship attributes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

We can always do :

```
EntityA @OneToOne EntityB

@OneToOne
@JoinTable(name="table_name")
private EntityB b;
```

**How will you ?**

**EntityC @OneToMany EntityD ( But this time I also have EntityType information on join )**

But what if you have `relationship` properties associated ?

Like:

```
EntityC  -- JoinTable -- EntityD
                |
                |
              EntityType
```

Now in this case my join table has 3 ids ( `EntityC_id, EntityType_id, EntityD_id` )

How can I create an association with `EntityC and EntityD` ( With EntityType ) ?

Comment: Ask for more clarifications if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the standard way is to create an entity representing `JoinTable` with `@OnetoMany` references from your `EntityC` and `EntityD`. `JoinTable` then has its own inverse `@ManyToOne` references. Such as (from the [JPA wikibook on M:N with additional columns](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns)):

```
@Entity
public class EntityC {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="entityC")
  private List<JoinTable> entityDs;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class EntityD {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="entityD")
  private List<JoinTable> entityCs;
  ...
}
```

Your association table is then managed as a separate entity, mapping these two entities to each other:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(JoinTableId.class)
public class JoinTable {
  @Id
  private long entityCId;
  @Id
  private long entityDId;
  ...
  private int entityTypeId;     //your relationship-attribute
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="entityCId", referencedColumnName="id", updatable="false", insertable="false")
  private EntityC entityC;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="entityDId", referencedColumnName="id", updatable="false", insertable="false")
  private EntityD entityD;
  ...
}

public class JoinTableId implements Serializable {
    private long entityCId;
    private long entityDId;
    ...
    //hashCode()
    //equals(...)
}
```

Note that this is criticised for its duplication and redundancy of id fields across the `JoinTable` class and its id class, which is required by JPA. See [Giannigar's blog](http://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/)  for an alternative suggestion (with credits).

*N.B. I've hand edited a lot of this so apologies for any typos.*